# How can I open a Word VSTO Document outside of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, vsto, document

I made a project in Visual Studio using C# of type **Word VSTO Document** and it works fine but the problem is that I can only open the docuement directly from the Visual Studio IDE by running my code.
How can I open this document with all the functionalities that I have created outside of the IDE?
I am new to programming and any help will be gladly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: Do you want to run the document level add-in on another machine or you have got problems with running it outside of VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking to deploy the solution you've created, as the VSTO file is only meant to be opened in Visual Studio.

You can read up on how to deploy said solution [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution?view=vs-2022).  There appears to be two options:

- [ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2022)
- [Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-a-vsto-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2022)